# meteor : setting fields post opening dialog

Tags: meteor, sample

I'm trying to complete the parties demo 
 with an "edit party" feature
I understood the create Dialog opens upon setting Session showCreateDialog

```
{{#if showCreateDialog}}
    {{> createDialog}}
 {{/if}}
```

this shows the popin 
but I want to set to fields post opening 
and I don't see how to act after the opening action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set manipulate the DOM inside the Template's [rendered event](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered). But if you find yourself writing lots of glue code here (`$("#someInput").val("someVal")`) then **watch out** because you're likely on the wrong track!

```
Template.createDialog.rendered = function() {
    // you can manipulate the DOM here
}
```

Remember, you can bind field values to instances, so something like the below will auto-bind your object

```
<template name="editDialog">
    {{#with party}}
        <input type="text" id="myPartyName" value="{{name}}" />
        ...
    {{/with}}
</template>

Template.editDialog.party = function() {
    return Parties.findOne(Session.get("selectedParty"));
};
```